# Foursquare: Authomatic bulkclaim venues

Tags: foursquare

this is a case for the real estate sector

is it possible to add residences for sale as a venue of the agency ? (not representing the office, but the product it self)?

Can this be done automatically through the real estate side (like a API feed to 4square) instead of using the bulkclaim excel file?

Will the system allow to manage authomaticly  the venues (homes for sale) and delete them once they're sold?

Answer (score 0):

You can always add venues using the [venues/add](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/add) endpoint, but you may not be able to instantly delete the venues. Also note that it's against foursquare's policies to add a person's home on foursquare without their explicit consent.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, this would be something that would only happen if the owner of the house authorizes it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, this would be something that would only happen if the owner of the house authorizes it. Do you know if this feature can be done authomaticaly ? I'm a business owner and not a developer so perdon my ignorance as i'm trying to figure out is foursquare can be used in my business. the idea seems interesting as it will give more autonomy for anyone looking for a house in a certain neighborhood .... other variables are still under research. thanks again

Comment: The process can be automated via the API, but that would require engineering work on your part.

Comment: Thanks Akdotcom. I thought so, do you recomend anyone that can make this happen?. I assume its a simple thing

Comment: We don't have a list of engineers for contracting work, sorry